# Minikube - External IP not match host's public IP

Tags: local, minikube

Shortly, I use GOOGLE COMPUTE ENGINE (external IP: 34.73.89.55, all ports and protocols are opened), then I install Docker, minikube, kubectl. Then:

```
minikube start --driver=docker

minikube tunnel

kubectl create deployment hello-minikube1 --image=k8s.gcr.io/echoserver:1.4

kubectl expose deployment hello-minikube1 --type=LoadBalancer --port=8080

kubectl get svc
```

and I get:

```
NAME              TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP      PORT(S)          AGE

hello-minikube1   LoadBalancer   10.110.130.109   10.110.130.109   8080:31993/TCP   9m22s
```

My question is, why the EXTERNAL-IP did not match with the host's external IP: 34.73.89.55? How can I access this service remotely by the host's external IP (ex: I'm at home and access via browser)?

Ps: I would like to use GOOGLE COMPUTE ENGINE.

EDIT:
I also try:

```
 sudo minikube start --driver=none

 sudo kubectl create deployment hello-minikube1 --image=k8s.gcr.io/echoserver:1.4

 sudo kubectl expose deployment hello-minikube1 --type=NodePort --port=8080

 wget 127.0.0.1:8080
```

=>not work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default minikube expects to run in a separate VM. This can be changed by explicitly specifying a driver.

1. `Why the EXTERNAL-IP did not match with the host's external IP?`

Because minikube uses a tunnel which creates a route to services deployed with type LoadBalancer and sets their Ingress to their ClusterIP. For a
detailed example see [this documentation](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/#using-minikube-tunnel).

2. `How can I access this service remotely by the host's external IP?`

I see two options here:

- More recommended: Set `--driver=none`

> Minikube also supports a `--driver=none` option that runs the
>   Kubernetes components on the host and not in a VM. Using this driver
>   requires Docker and a Linux environment but not a hypervisor.

- Might be less ideal: Use [port forwarding](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/) (either using iptables or proxy). This might be less ideal.

Also remember that minikube was created for testing purposes on locahost. Keep that in mind while using it.

EDIT:

When going for `--driver=none` you can:

- Use NodePort type instead of LoadBalancer.
- Continue using Loadbalancer with a modified Service by adding:

`spec:
 externalIPs:
 - <host_address>`

For example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
 creationTimestamp: null
 labels:
   app: hello-minikube1
 name: hello-minikube1
spec:
 externalIPs:
 - <host_address>
 ports:
 - port: 8080
   protocol: TCP
   targetPort: 8080
 selector:
   app: hello-minikube1
 type: LoadBalancer
status:
 loadBalancer: {}
```

The above was tested and resulted in EXTERNAL IP = HOST IP.

Please let me know if that helped.

Comment: Hi, if I set --driver=none, do i need tunnel? Which type should I use (LoadBalancer/NodePort)?

Comment: Hi, I repeat exactly the step in my question, but let driver=none. and the result as the same. I still cannot access 127.0.0.1:8080, but EXTERNAL-IP:8080 works.

Comment: Let me edit the answer in order to address your concerns.

Comment: Many thanks, but seems that it not work :(
Let's I summarize steps in my edit

Comment: @SoT Have you tried to use LoadBalancer with a modified Service as I have shown? Or only the nodeport as you said in your edit?

Comment: Firstly, many thanks for your effort you spent for me. I'll try loadbalancer and tell you the result soon.

Comment: Hi @OhHiMark, I tried load balancer as your yaml and it get working fine! Many Thanks